# fastest way to find list of files in a huge windows directory tree

Tags: java, windows, file-io

I have a windows directory tree with about 1,000,000 files inside.
I have a text file that i read in Java, contains some file names (about 100,000), and I want to check for every file name - if it exists in the directory (if yes - give me a full path of the file).

Already tried those options:

1.

```
File folder = new File("your/path");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
  if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
    System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
  } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
  }
}
```

2.

```
public void func(String path, String name)
{

    Path folder = Paths.get(path);
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(folder))
    {
        for (Path entry : stream) 
        {
            if(Files.isDirectory(entry))
            {
                func(entry.toString(), name);
            }
            else
            {
                if(FilenameUtils.removeExtension(entry.getFileName().toString()).equals(name))
                {
                    System.out.println(entry);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
    // An I/O problem has occurred
    }

}
```

So far all those options to do so are very slow.
As I guess, although all the files are in the same logic place, actually every file is saved in another place in the hard drive, so all those IO calls take too much time.

Another idea that i found here is ISearchFolderItemFactory interface, but I found documentation for it only in C++, not in Java.

Maybe I can implement a pre-sort or something, to put all the files really together in the hd, sorted by name, and then to use some hash method to find name by name?

Need some help...

Comment: The code snippets in your question don't traverse the directory tree. Please show your actual code, especially the data structure you use to hold the 100.000 file names of interest and the part where you decide whether the current file is part of the interesting ones.

Comment: a. The traverse is not the issue but anyway I edited my post and added it. b.  I don't hold all the 100,000 files. I read a simple text file line by line and send every line to this method (sounds not so efficient. that's why I posted this question). The file names are written in the text file.  c. a simple "equals" comparison, dropping the extension.

Comment: You should definitely read the text file with the 100,000 file names in advance and store them in a HashSet. Then it is efficient to check whether the current file is contained in the set or not.

Comment: I have more logic to do for every file, but shortly, I must know which file relate to which line in the text file, so reading in advance will not be so helpful. but tnx.

Comment: What is the alternative? Do you read the whole file in for each file to check in the file system? It seems this is your biggest performance problem. Why do you think it is not possible to read the file beforehand and store all the necessary information, maybe in a map? That's why I initially asked for the real code.

Comment: Additionally, you should consider [Files.walkFileTree()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-) to traverse the files. It visits all files  in a directory including all subdirectories.

Comment: Since you are asking for the *"fastest way"* (as opposed to something, that's fast enough) you're going to have to code against the file system, NTFS for example, and parse the raw tables.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're querying the file system for the names of approximately _1,000,000_ files for _each line_ in your approximately _100,000_ line list-of-names file? That seems incredibly inefficient. As already suggested, you should really read all the names into memory _first_ and then walk the file tree _only one time_. As you said you need to know which line the file name was in, you could store them in a `Map<String, Integer>`.

Comment: Thanks guys, you gave me some good ideas... Instead of comparing each line to all files, I walk the files one time and try to find each file in the hash. Going to implement...Thanks!!